# What was the largest ratio (result size)/(integrand size) you have seen?

Tags: calculus, integration, soft-question, definite-integrals, big-list

Sometimes a definite or indefinite integral of a simple-looking one-liner integrand can give astonishingly huge result. What was the largest ratio of the size of shortest known closed-form result to the size of the corresponding integrand you have seen? I am particularly interested in *unexpectedly* large results, not those, for example, that occur from an intentionally large exponent in the integrand or otherwise obviously tailored for that purpose.

Comment: What about $\int\cos^{2013}x\,dx$?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Good comment! I edited the question to try to exclude cases like this (although in somewhat vague way).

Comment: If you insist on writing $\int dx/(x^4+x+1)$ in terms of radicals
as you did in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516263
(rather than leaving it in terms of the roots of the denominator)
then the indefinite integral will look horrendous.  Even worse
if the denominator is a polynomial of higher degree with a solvable
but complicated Galois group such as the solvable $168$-element
subgroup of $A_8$ (obtained from the $ax+b$ group over ${\bf F}_8$
by adjoining the field automorphisms of ${\bf F}_8$).
[This is not an answer because I haven't actually *seen* such a formula...]

Comment: Not an integral, but I remember vividly my astonishment seeing a computer printout of the solution to

solve(x^4 + a*x^3 + b*x^2 + c*x + d = 0, x)

some 25 years ago, when Mathematica was released unto the world. It made me realize there are better ways to solve equations than learning formulas by heart.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\int\ \ln(x+a) \cdot ln(x+b) \cdot ln(x+c)\ dx\ -$ It spews forth a [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4CJK.png) almost the size of my entire screen, even with *Full Simplify* $^{and}/_{or}$ *Function Expand* activated . . .

$\int\ \sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)}\ dx\ -$ The same, only that this time its size is about seven full screens of resolution $1366\times768$, even with *Simplify* on.

Comment: [awesome](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+ln%28x%2Ba%29+ln%28x%2Bb%29ln%28x%2Bc%29dx)

Answer (score 3):

The following example I learned from James Davenport (Cambridge UK):

[image]