# $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos{x}\sqrt{1+\tan{x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Find this integral
$$I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos{x}\sqrt{1+\tan{x}}dx$$

My try:I find this wolf can't find it. [**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cpi%7D%5Ccos%7Bx%7D%5Csqrt%7B1%2B%5Ctan%7Bx%7D%7Ddx)

then I try: let 
$$\sqrt{1+\tan{x}}=t\Longrightarrow x=\arctan{(t^2-1)}$$
so
$$I=\int_{1}^{+\infty}\cos{\left(\arctan{(t^2-1)}\right)}\dfrac{2t^2}{(t^2-1)^2}dt$$

Then I can't

Comment: *Mathematica* returns a value for the definite integral expressed in terms of the [Meijer G function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function).

Comment: @Lucian. If you want fun, just compute the antiderivative and post it !

Comment: I'm running *FullSimplify[...]* on that dreadful formula as we speak... :-) P.S.: I've posted, or at least mentioned, two such monsters on [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509076/what-was-the-largest-ratio-result-size-integrand-size-you-have-seen) post.

Comment: It would be a good exercise for students to show that the improper integral is convergent. I am writing this one down!

Comment: It maybe this integral can use  Special constant,such as gamma,and Eluer constant,Catalan’s Constant and so on

Comment: Don't know if this will be helpful or not, but another equivalent form of the integral is $I = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1+u}}{(1+u^2)^{\frac32}}\space du$.

Comment: Another form of this integral is 

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}}\mathrm{d}y$$

and maybe it can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$\ds{\large%
I \equiv \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos\pars{x}\root{1 + \tan\pars{x}}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> I&=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\root{\cos^{2}\pars{x} + \sin\pars{x}\cos\pars{x}}\,\dd x
> =
> \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\root{{1 + \cos\pars{2x} \over 2} + {\sin\pars{2x} \over 2}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=
> {1 \over 4}\,\root{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}\root{1 + \cos\pars{x} + \sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x
> =
> {1 \over 4}\,\root{2}
> \int_{0}^{\pi}\root{1 + \root{2}\sin\pars{x + {\pi \over 4}}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=
> {1 \over 4}\,\root{2}
> \int_{\pi/4}^{5\pi/4}\root{1 + \root{2}\sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x
> \end{align}

The $\it\underline{last\ integral}$ is evaluated [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint%5Csqrt%7B1+%2B+a+sin%28x%29%7D+dx) in terms of a Second Kind Elliptic function.

Answer (score 1):

This is an awful integral ! The formula for the antiderivative write in several pages. The numerical value is : 1.3571445175439115954095406.

Comment: I think this integral can take some constant

Comment: The result is a constant as posted by Lucian.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote earlier, its value is non-elementary, and expressible in terms of the [Meijer G function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function):

[image]

The expression of its anti-derivative can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccCDF.png). It involves [incomplete elliptic integrals of the first and second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral).